# error: [Orderer.js]: sendBroadcast - on error: "Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE:.. Hyperledger Caliper

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-caliper

I have setup hyperledger fabric version 1.4.2 with 1 org 2 peers 1 orderer setup all are running in 3 different VMs natively. Now I am trying to implement caliper v0.3.0 in this fabric setup. Peers and Orderer are already up and peers are joined in the channel. I have modified the network config file and benchconfig file in caliper according to my network. So I directly run the caliper using the flag "caliper-flow-only-install". While executing this, I am facing issues like

error: [Orderer.js]: sendBroadcast - on error: "Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: failed to connect to all addresses\n at Object.exports.createStatusError (/home/xx/caliper-benchmarks/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)\n at ClientDuplexStream._emitStatusIfDone (/home/xx/caliper-benchmarks/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:233:26)\n at ClientDuplexStream._receiveStatus (/home/xx/caliper-benchmarks/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:211:8)\n at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/xx/caliper-benchmarks/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1306:15)\n at InterceptingListener._callNext (/home/xx/caliper-benchmarks/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)\n at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/home/xx/caliper-benchmarks/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:618:8)\n at /home/xx/caliper-benchmarks/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1123:18"
2020.04.29-12:22:12.094 error [caliper] [caliper-engine] Error while performing "install" step: Error: Orderer error for instantiating W1CC@v0 in composerchannelrest: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is with using incorrect docker container port mapping.

Use the host port rather docker container port.

You can even cross check connection to container with network utility.

For instance, nc -vz [host] [port]

Hope this resolves SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE error.